# How to Bind ViewCell to TableView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement `TableView` in `Xamarin.Forms`, in each cell I need to place image and two label ,for that I have implemented `ViewCell` and now how to add `ViewCell` to `tableview` in `Xamarin.Forms`

Comment: XAML or C#? What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi thanks for replay ,what are control we can bind to viewable in Xamarin.forms

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication ,what are control we can bind to ViewCell in Xamarin.forms

Comment: You can bind any Xamarin.Forms View to a ViewCell